# Distribution of areas in regular $n$-gon with diagonals, as $n\to\infty$

Tags: geometry, limits, probability-distributions, area, polygons

Consider a regular $n$-gon with all diagonals drawn. Here is an example with $n=10$.

[image]

What is the distribution of the areas of the regions, as $n\to\infty$ ?

That is, if we write down each region's area, how are those numbers distributed? What does the density function look like?

The number of regions is approximately $\dfrac{1}{24}n^4$ for large $n$. [Here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonDiagonalIntersectionGraph.html) is an exact formula for the number of regions.

Context: I've been thinking about regular $n$-gons with connected vertices, and this question naturally arose.

UPDATE

I found a nice [geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/AXE5mRgH) that allows you to play with various regular polygons with all diagonals drawn.

I would not be surprised if the answer to my question is currently unknown, because the following related question, which seems simpler than my question, is an [open question](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C%203%2C%204%2C%205%2C%204%2C%206%2C%205%2C%206%2C%204%2C%208&language=english&go=Search): If a regular *n*-gon has all its diagonal drawn, does there exist a bound on the maximum number of sides of the sub-polygons thus formed (excluding the central sub-polygon when *n* is odd)?

UPDATE2

This question has inspired another question: [Regular polygon of radius $1$ with diagonals: mysterious ring of radius $1/e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590337/regular-polygon-of-radius-1-with-diagonals-mysterious-ring-of-radius-1-e?noredirect=1#comment9666004_4590337)