# In a regular *n*-gon with $n>4$, side length $1$ and all diagonals drawn, can any cell have rational area?

Tags: geometry, area, rational-numbers, polygons

In a regular *n*-gon with $n>4$, side length $1$ and all diagonals drawn, can any cell have rational area? (By "cell", I mean one of the sub-polygons, with no diagonal cutting through it.)

Here is a [geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/AXE5mRgH) where you can see a regular polygon with $n$ sides ($3\leq n\leq50$) and all diagonals drawn.

**My attempt**

I know that the angles between intersecting diagonals of the *n*-gon are rational multiples of $\pi$, and I know that the sine or cosine of such angles are [algebraic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933177/proof-that-a-trigonometric-function-of-a-rational-angle-must-be-non-transcendent). I have tried to divide the cells into triangles (by drawing line segments between vertices) and expressing the area of the triangles as $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin{\theta}$. But I do not know how to make this approach work.

(Context: this question is a follow-up to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479299/distribution-of-areas-in-regular-n-gon-with-all-diagonals-drawns-as-n-to-inf) about the distribution of the areas in a regular polygon with diagonals drawn.)

Comment: The trig functions of rational multiples of $\pi$ are algebraic, not transcendental. E.g., $\sin(\pi/4)=\sqrt2/2$, $\sin(\pi/6)=1/2$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oops, I meant algebraic. Corrected.