# Regular polygon with diagonals: bounds on area of largest cell?

Tags: geometry, area, supremum-and-infimum, polygons

Consider a regular $n$-gon of side length $1$ with its diagonals. Here is an example with $n=11$ (from [geogebra applet](https://www.geogebra.org/m/AXE5mRgH)).

[image]

Excluding the centre cell when $n$ is odd, I've been trying to find bounds on the area of the largest cell, in terms of $n$.

It seems that, for every value of $n$, the largest non-centre cell has roughly similar area as the outermost cell, whose area is $\frac{1}{4}\tan{\frac{\pi}{n}}\approx\frac{\pi}{4n}$.

[image]

That is, $(\text{area of largest non-centre cell})\approx\frac{\pi}{4n}$. (This claim has strong numerical [evidence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4591233/398708).)

My question is:

> In a regular $n$-gon of side length $1$ with diagonals, what is the infimum and supremum of $n\times(\text{area of largest non-centre cell})$ ?

(The number of cells is approximately [$\frac{1}{24}n^4$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonDiagonalIntersectionGraph.html) for large $n$.)

Comment: I believe the area of each cell bordering an edge of the polygon is also $\frac{\pi}{4n}(1+o(1))$. So the claim is tantamount to the claim that no interior region has area much smaller than those regions.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut I'm not sure I follow. The claim (that area of largest non-centre region is $\frac{\pi}{4n}(1+o(1))$) does not say something about all the interior regions; it just says something about the largest non-centre interior region.

Comment: Sure, but this provides a lower bound: there exists a non-center interior region with area $\frac{\pi}{4n}(1+o(1))$.

Comment: [Posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436753/regular-n-gon-with-diagonals-bounds-on-area-of-largest-cell) on MO.